# Z-функция. Реализация поиска

Tags: c++, строки

Требуется реализовать поиск подстроки в строке с использованием Z-функции.

Нужен или код или алгоритм, т.к. в интернете есть вычисление самой Z-функции, но не объяснение, как понять, что у нас подстрока входит в строку.

P.S. Нашел псевдокод - но он мне не понятен:

```
 int substringSearch(text : string, pattern : string):
   int[] zf = zFunction(pattern + '#' + text)
   for i = m + 1 to n + 1
     if zf[i] == m 
       return i
```

Comment: Такие вопросы без предоставления того, что вы  сделали, и что у вас не получается, как правило, сразу же закрываются.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow,
Извините, конечно. НО! Данный вопрос напрямую относится к программированию. А также я попросил алгоритм, или, если точнее, объяснение алгоритма. Не думаю, что в мире существует много разных Z-функций (не в плане алгоритма, а в плане возращаемого значения).
Мой же вопрос - как применить данное значение для нахождения вхождения подстроки в строке. Если бы я привел один из сотни алгоритмов - толку от этого не было бы - т.к. про Z-функцию знают многие, и это только отвлекало бы людей.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Это как выкопать колодец, поставить рядом ведро и не понимать как быть дальше, т.к. нужно это ведро опустить в колодец. Но не важно какой колодец - в любом сслучае привязываем веревку, бирем мыло и .... Вжух....

Comment: А что означают числа в массиве после вычисления z-функции?

Comment: https://e-maxx.ru/algo/z_function

Comment: @MBo что-то там с префиксом - максимальный префикс, вроде

Comment: @BeaverFeller Спасибо - долго искал, где есть алгоритм поиска - вы прям спасли меня от хвоста

Comment: @Alrott SlimRG Так если разобраться с сутью того, что лежит в массиве, наверное, будет понятно, что проверяется в псевдокоде...

Comment: @MBo увы - но не все так просто (по крайней мере для меня)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

P.S. Спасибо, Beaver Feller - это он нашел сайт с ответом.

P.P.S. Всех с Новым Годом!